# MPI partition and communication in 2D topology (velocity directions)

Tags: c, mpi, decomposition

I found [this program](http://www.cas.usf.edu/~cconnor/parallel/2dheat/2d_heat_equation.c) and my question is... Is it possible to change communication and neighborhood in this program as here?

[image: LBM Domain Decomposition pict (a)]

I need partition a 2D array into 4 blocks between processors (on each of them only one process should work). Additional i must use lattice model stencil (9 points), not so as in conway game of life (5 point stencil)

Im not sure, whether 2d cartesian virtual topology in MPI provides the use more than 4 directions for exchange data. Maybe I should use graph? And I don't know how and I can't find any information about exchange data in diagonal directions between tiles/halo/ghosts. Somebody can explain this? I really need help :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual topology in MPI is just a mechanism for mapping abstract coordinates to ranks and vice versa. That two processes are not neighbours in a Cartesian topology does not prevent them at all from communicating.

The reason you are not finding any information on diagonal halo exchange is because it is not at all necessary to do it explicitly as it happens as a side effect of the regular halo exchange when the local halo cells are also included in the exchange.

The following illustrates how a typical 2D halo exchange is implemented. Pay close attention to how the elements denoted with capital letters move. The source columns/rows are marked with double `v`/`<` and the destination ones with single `v`/`<`.

Initial configuration

```
......      ......      ......
.aaaa.      .bbbb.      .cccc.
.aaaa.      .bbbb.      .cccc.
.aaaA.      .BbbB.      .Cccc.
......      ......      ......

......      ......      ......
.dddD.      .EeeE.      .Ffff.
.dddd.      .eeee.      .ffff.
.dddd.      .eeee.      .ffff.
......      ......      ......
```

Halo exchange in positive direction along the first dimension:

```
    v           v
    v       v   v       v
......      ......      ......
.aaaa.      abbbb.      bcccc.
.aaaa. ---> abbbb. ---> bcccc.
.aaaA.      ABbbB.      BCccc.
......      ......      ......

......      ......      ......
.dddD.      DEeeE.      EFfff.
.dddd. ---> deeee. ---> effff.
.dddd.      deeee.      effff.
......      ......      ......
```

Halo exchange in negative direction along the first dimension:

```
             v           v
     v       v   v       v
......      ......      ......
.aaaab      abbbbc      bcccc.
.aaaab <--- abbbbc <--- bcccc.
.aaaAB      ABbbBC      BCccc.
......      ......      ......

......      ......      ......
.dddDE      DEeeEF      EFfff.
.dddde <--- deeeef <--- effff.
.dddde      deeeef      effff.
......      ......      ......
```

Halo exchange in positive direction along the second dimension:

```
......      ......      ......
.aaaab      abbbbc      bcccc.
.aaaab      abbbbc      bcccc.
.aaaAB      ABbbBC      BCccc. <<
......      ......      ......
   |           |           |
   v           v           v
.aaaAB      ABbbBC      BCccc. <
.dddDE      DEeeEF      EFfff.
.dddde      deeeef      effff.
.dddde      deeeef      effff.
......      ......      ......
```

Halo exchange in negative direction along the second dimension:

```
......      ......      ......
.aaaab      abbbbc      bcccc.
.aaaab      abbbbc      bcccc.
.aaaAB      ABbbBC      BCccc.
.dddDE      DEeeEF      EFfff. <
   ^           ^           ^
   |           |           |
.aaaAB      ABbbBC      BCccc.
.dddDE      DEeeEF      EFfff. <<
.dddde      deeeef      effff.
.dddde      deeeef      effff.
......      ......      ......
```

It is important that for halo exchanges along all dimensions after the first one the entire slab, including the local halo cells, is exchanged. For simplicity, one usually includes the halo cells in the first exchange too.

Each step could be easily implemented using a single `MPI_Sendrecv` call. Thus, one needs two `MPI_Sendrecv` per direction for a total of four calls in the 2D case. Ranks to send to/receive from are easily obtainable using `MPI_Cart_shift`. Another MPI feature that has to be used is vector datatypes (`MPI_Type_vector`), which allows for accessing columns of C/C++ arrays. With three- or higher-dimensional topologies the `MPI_Type_create_subarray` function comes handy.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the communication in two synchronous steps via :

1. Send top and bottom rows of border nodes up an down respectively.
2. Send the extended left and right columns of border nodes (that is, the border nodes the processor owns plus the top and bottom node for each of these border columns that was just recieved), to the left and right neighbors.

And it would be beneficial to overlap this communication with the computations required on the processor interior nodes.